# Diferencia entre contentChild y viewChild

Tags: javascript, angular

¿Cuál es la diferencia y los usos de `@ContentChild` y `@ViewChild` en Angular 7?

Answer (score 2):

**ViewChild**

Se considera `ViewChild` a todo elemento que está dentro del propio template del componente; es decir, todo lo que esté dentro del template.

**ContentChild**

Un `ContentChild` es similar a un `ViewChild`, sin embargo, la diferencia sustancial es que se considera solo los elementos hijos del elemento ya *hosteado*; es decir, cualquier hijo del componente como tal (no del template).

---

Imaginemos que tienes un componente `Card` con su template:

```
<div class="card">
  <header class="card__header">
      <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
  </header>
  <article class="card__body">
     <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-content>
</div>
```

Aquí, tanto `div.card` como `header.card__header` como `article.card__body` son **ViewChild**.

Ahora, al usar el componente:

```
<ui-card>
    <div class="picture">
      ...
    </div>
</ui-card>
```

El elemento `div.picture` vendría a ser un **ContentChild**.

**Resumen**

`ViewChild`: hijo dentro del template.
`ContentChild`: hijo dentro del componente (como host).